# How to make a unit step function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, functions

I am trying to make a unit step function.

I have this function (the equation of an ellipse, not centered at the origin):

$$
f(x,y) = \frac{(x-X_c)^2}{a^2}+\frac{(y-Y_c)^2}{b^2}
$$

What I would like to, is present it as a unit step function with the attributes saying if the result of f(x,y) is between 0.95 and 1.05 then return 1, otherwise return 0. Is this possible? If so, how do I do it?

I hope you understand my question, and I am looking forward to help.

-David

Comment: relevant: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CharacteristicFunction.html

Answer (score 1):

Let $u(x)$ be the unit step function.  You want the function $g(z)=u(z-0.95)-u(z-1.05)$.  Replace z with $f(x,y)$